# Tensorflow decode image

Tags: image, tensorflow

I am a beginner in tensorflow and I am training a small cnn, I am using the tf.io.decode_image function but I can't figure out if this function does preprocess.
The tensorflow documentation about it doesn't say anything.
When I open images with this function the values are between 0 and 1.
The images are single channel grayscale.
This is the code.

```
def decode_img(self, imgs, channels):
        # Convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
        images = []
        for element in imgs:

            dec_image = tf.io.decode_image(element, channels=channels, dtype=tf.float32)
            try:
                img = keras.utils.img_to_array(dec_image)
            except AttributeError:
                img = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(dec_image)
            images.append(img)
        images = np.array(images)
        return images
```

I would like to have more explanations

Comment: imgs is a array composed of tf.io.read_file,